# Enable and display comment in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I downgraded my WordPress site only to discover that my comment box no longer display and that comment is disabled on my site, though I don't know when this issue started, might be earlier before the downgrade.

I have checked all the possible setting and everything is all enabled as it should be, but comment still don't work.

Comment is well enabled on the Discussion tab, also enable on my Newspaper theme and also enabled on Jetpack plugin.

Please is there any code I can use to enable comment on my function.php or comment.php or any relevant file in the code base.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is missing some details that people may need to effectively answer your question, such as the versions of WordPress the site runs on. If possible, consider including a [mcve] from the files you describe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/